# Pictures position break responsiveness

Tags: php, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I placed 2 pictures (facebook and youtube) to my header, however, the problem now is they seems not click-able despite they are links and when view in mobile, they are blocked by the contact number on the top.

http://seaicf.com

I'm out of idea on how to fix this, can anyone help?

Here's my header.php until the line where I insert the pictures:

```php
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div id="page-container">
<?php
    if ( is_page_template( 'page-template-blank.php' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $et_secondary_nav_items = et_divi_get_top_nav_items();

    $et_phone_number = $et_secondary_nav_items->phone_number;

    $et_email = $et_secondary_nav_items->email;

    $et_contact_info_defined = $et_secondary_nav_items->contact_info_defined;

    $show_header_social_icons = $et_secondary_nav_items->show_header_social_icons;

    $et_secondary_nav = $et_secondary_nav_items->secondary_nav;

    $primary_nav_class = 'et_nav_text_color_' . et_get_option( 'primary_nav_text_color', 'dark' );

    $secondary_nav_class = 'et_nav_text_color_' . et_get_option( 'secondary_nav_text_color', 'light' );

    $et_top_info_defined = $et_secondary_nav_items->top_info_defined;
?>

    <?php if ( $et_top_info_defined ) : ?>
        <div id="top-header" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $secondary_nav_class ); ?>">
            <div class="container clearfix">
              <div class="container clearfix">
            <?php
                $logo = ( $user_logo = et_get_option( 'divi_logo' ) ) && '' != $user_logo
                    ? $user_logo
                    : $template_directory_uri . '/images/logo.png';
            ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_attr( $logo ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" id="logo" />
                </a>


            <?php if ( $et_contact_info_defined ) : ?>

                <div id="et-info">
                <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_phone_number = et_get_option( 'phone_number' ) ) ) : ?>
                    <span id="et-info-phone"><?php echo esc_html( $et_phone_number ); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_email = et_get_option( 'header_email' ) ) ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( 'mailto:' . $et_email ); ?>"><span id="et-info-email"><?php echo esc_html( $et_email ); ?></span></a>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php
                if ( true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
                    get_template_part( 'includes/socialGoogle analytic_icons', 'header' );
                } ?>


                </div>
                </div> <!-- #et-info -->

               <ul class="et-social-icons">

                 <div><a href="http://www.facebook.com"target="_blank"><img  src="http://seaicf.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/facebooklike.png" width="75" height="25"/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.youtube.com"target="_blank"><img src="http://seaicf.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/youtube.png" width="75" height="25"></a></div>
```

Updated with the CSS that controls the classes in that header:

```css
#top-header .container {
padding-top: 10px;
}

.container {
text-align: left;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1080px;
position: relative;
}

media="all"
#top-header .et-social-icons {
float: right;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: -37px;
-moz-margin-top: 5px;
-webkit-margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: The negative margin really messes everything up. Add a `@media` css query that overrides the negative margin with `margin:0` for the needed width and it should be fine.

Comment: Hi @ITroubs, thanks a lot for replying, the freelancer I hired really messed things up. Do you mean in the CSS? I'm not sure where should I add them.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to float the two wrappers to the right makes things hard. It is easier to just have one left column on the left and one on the right. In the one on the right you can then place add an extra wrapper div to have the social media buttons appear under the phone number:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <a href="http://seaicf.com/%e9%a6%96%e9%a1%b5/">
    <img src="http://seaicf.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logo-75.png" alt="ISI MonQ Academy" id="logo">
    </a>
    <div id="et-info">
        <div>
            <span id="et-info-phone">1800-800-800</span>
            <a href="mailto:info@seaicf.com"><span id="et-info-email">info@seaicf.com</span></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="et-social-icons">
            <div>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://seaicf.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/facebooklike.png" height="25" width="75"></a>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://seaicf.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/youtube.png" height="25" width="75"></a>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Floating things is complicated, just replace the classes you made with this:

```
.container {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1080px;
    position: relative;
}

#top-header .et-social-icons {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#et-info {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
I followed your code however, the 2 social pictures are appearing lower now and looks very far apart from the contact number, it was initially this way but we wanted to move it nearer to the contact number, what we done has achieved the layout we want but function wise it didn't work.

Do you have other way to solve this?

Comment: Please provide your code, as on my system the solution works fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/pxntusnd/1/

Comment: Just isolating the problematic part in a fiddle may already point you in the direction what goes wrong anyway :)

Comment: I'm using Wordpress theme Divi, I'm not sure is it whether other classes are affecting the style as well.
I've pasted the CSS and header.php into this pastebin if you could have a look.
CSS: http://pastebin.com/VCqcgr3p
header.php: http://pastebin.com/wpLE987J

Comment: I think you still have to change some of your HTML. I've pasted your complete stylesheet into the fiddle, removed 'text-align: center' from the line with .et-social-icons, #footer-info.
Here, have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/pxntusnd/2/